# Jquery mobile flip toggle select at least one from two buttons.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have two flip toggle buttons in my html, if the user have gender value for male "off" and then the user selects  gender value for female "off", the the male button will switch automatically to "on" and vice versa. In other words: if one flip switch is deselected and leaves both switches deselected, I want to select the opposite button.

html:

```
<div data-role="content" id="settingsPanel">
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="menSelector" >    
        <label for="flip-1">Men</label>
        <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider"data-mini="true"onclick="toggleRule()>
            <option value="off"></option>
            <option selected="selected" value="on"></option>
        </select> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="womenSelector" >  
        <label for="flip-2">Women</label>
        <select name="flip-2" id="flip-2" data-role="slider"data-mini="true"onclick="toggleRule()>
            <option value="off"></option>
            <option selected="selected" value="on"></option>                
        </select>           
    </div>
```

My no working attempt:

```
 function toggleRule() {
// If the value is off, and female is off, then select automatically female on
if ($("flip-1").val()=="off" && $("flip-2").val()=="off"){ //condition one
    $("flip-2").val()=="on";
}
else if ($("flip-2").val()=="off" && $("flip-1").val()=="off"){ //contition 2
    $("flip-1").val()=="on";
}
};
```

Comment: use OnChange instead of OnClick

Comment: Use `$("select[name='flip-X']")` instead of `$("flip-X")`.

Comment: Thanks @GenaMoroz @ojovirtual. I changed the onchange event attribute and added `$("select[name='flip-X']")` but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach `change` event to both sliders `flip-1` and `flip-2`. Whenever one of them is changed, read its' value and update other slider accordingly. Most important part is to *refresh* sliders when you update their values programmatically `.slider("refresh")`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
    $("#flip-1, #flip-2").on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "on") {
            $("select")
                .not($(this))       /* select other slider */
                .val("off")         /* update its' value */
                .slider("refresh"); /* refresh it */
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "off") {
            $("select")
                .not($(this))
                .val("on")
                .slider("refresh");
        }
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/c4rcdvcb/)**

Comment: @user3356128 not to vote. Click "correct" sign underneath downvoter arrow. You'll get 2 rep points ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your question that both can be on, but both cannot be off.

In that case, handle the change event on each flipswitch. If the value is off set the other one to on and refresh the flipswitch widget.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $("#flip-1").on("change", function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "off"){
             //turn on flip-2 
            $("#flip-2").val("on").slider( "refresh" );
        }
    });
    $("#flip-2").on("change", function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "off"){
             //turn on flip-1 
            $("#flip-1").val("on").slider( "refresh" );
        }
    });
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/acd2t4jf/2/)**

UPDATE: using Omar's technique, assign the same class to both switches (genderSelect in my example):

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="menSelector">
    <label for="flip-1">Men</label>
    <select id="flip-1" name="flip-1" data-role="slider" data-mini="true" class="genderSelect">
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option selected="" value="on">On</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="womenSelector">
    <label for="flip-2">Women</label>
    <select name="flip-2" id="flip-2" data-role="slider" data-mini="true" class="genderSelect">
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option selected="" value="on">On</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then handle one change event on that class:

```
$(".genderSelect").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "off") {
        $(".genderSelect").not($(this)).val("on").slider("refresh");
    }
});
```

Comment: it's a slider ;) `data-role="slider"`

Comment: Awesome @ezanker, thanks a lot! I hope I could vote up but I am new, need more votes up to vote, what a irony. :)

Comment: @Omar, thanks! Updated to use slider ;) I think your answer is more elegant, but I believe that OP requirement is that both switches can be on at the same time, just not both off. Maybe like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/c4rcdvcb/1/

Comment: @user3356128, have a look at Omar's answer as he does it in one event handler. If both switches can be on, just remove the if ($(this).val() == "on") {...} part.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I understood that he wants one switch selected always "_In other words: if one flip switch is deselected and leaves both switches deselected, I want to select the opposite button._". Anyway, he's got two answers to play with ;)

Comment: Thaks a lot @ezanker!